# How to sort string type date in list of string?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, arraylist

How can i sort the string date in list of string?

Input :

2019/5/9, 2019/5/13, 2019/5/14,2019/5/17,2019/5/19,2019/5/15,2019/5/18

Expected Output :

2019/5/9, 2019/5/13, 2019/5/14,2019/5/15,2019/5/16,2019/5/17,2019/5/18

My Code :

```
     Dim Mytargetlist As String = ""  
        Dim list As New List(Of String)      
        Mytargetlist = p(1) + "/" + p(2) + "/" + p(3)    
        list.Add(Mytargetlist)    
        'list.Sort()     
        Dim result As List(Of String) = list.Distinct().ToList
          If Session("mydata") Is Nothing Then
              Session("mydata") = New ArrayList
          End If
        TryCast(Session("mydata"), ArrayList).Add(result.ToArray())
```

Comment: Why not using SortedList? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort a List of dates , why not using a List(of Dates) ?

```
     Dim list As new List(of Date)
     list.add(New Date(2019,5,9))
     list.add(New Date(2019,5,9))
     list.add(New Date(2019,5,01))
     list.add(New Date(2019,5,25))
     list.add(New Date(2019,5,13))
     list.add(New Date(2019,5,30))
     list.add(New Date(2019,5,9))

     list.Sort()
    Dim myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    For Each item As Date In list

    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString(myFormat)) 
    Next
```

Output:
`01/05/2019
09/05/2019
09/05/2019
09/05/2019
13/05/2019
25/05/2019
30/05/2019`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as asked, you can call the overload of `Sort` that takes a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate and provide a Lambda that compares `Strings` as `Dates`:

```
list.Sort(Function(s1, s2)
              Dim d1 As Date
              Dim d2 As Date

              If Date.TryParse(s1, d1) AndAlso Date.TryParse(s2, d2) Then
                  'Both values convert so compare chronologically.
                  Return d1.CompareTo(d2)
              End If

              'At least one value does not convert so consider them equivalent.
              Return 0
          End Function)
```

That converts each value to an actual `Date` for the purposes of comparison.  If you want to do something specific when only one value converts successfully, e.g. invalid values always come last, you can implement that too.

That said, unless you have a very good reason for storing dates in `Strings`, you really ought to be using `Date` values in the first place.